# how to catch "previous/next" track change event in media player

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player

How do I catch "previous/next" track change event in axWindowsMediaPlayer1?

For example, when:

- user clicks on "Next" or "previous" button in Media Player
- or when following code executes `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.next();`
- or when following code executes `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.previous();`

So far I've tried to catch "axWindowsMediaPlayer1_**PlayStateChange**" event but it doesn't show if the "next" or "previous" track change event was triggered. All it shows is `e.newState = 9` (transitioning)

so how do i process "next" or "previous" track event before it is executed?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm wanting to do the same thing.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 sorry for the slow response. I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so apparently, that is impossible to do...

instead, I am catching a bunch of different events such as

```
if (e.newState == 8) // media ended

if (e.newState == 6) // buffering

else if (e.newState == 3) // playing
```

I am constantly checking which song is playing in the playlist. If it's the last song in the playlist, then trigger one action, if not the last one - then another... I know that is not something I expected, but we have to deal with the problem with available approaches.. even non-native ones.